# Uniform Convergence of derivative

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

**Question**

Suppose a sequence of derivatives of functions $f'_n $  converge uniformly to $f'$ where $f_n$ is defined on the on the interval $[a,b]$. And $f_n(x)$ converges pointwise to $f(x)$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$.

**Effort**

I basically just have the definition:

$1.$ $\forall \epsilon >0, \forall n >N, |f'_n(a)-f'(a)|<\epsilon, \forall a\in \mathbb{R}$

and  $\forall \epsilon ' >0, \forall n' >N', |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon '$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$

$2.$ Another point to note may be is : there exists a point $c$ such that $$\frac{f'_n(c)}{f'(c)}=\frac{f_n(b)-f_n(a)}{f(b)-f(a)}$$
Applying limit to both side$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f_n(b)-f_n(a)}{f(b)-f(a)}=1$$

It seems second one is right track but I don't seem to be able to complete it.

P.S. Not sure if it's related to functional analysis.

Comment: Approach 2 might go somewhere if you set $a=x_0$ and $b=x_0+h$.Then you get that $f_n(x_0+h)-f_n(x_0)\to f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)$ uniformly with respect to $h$. Since $f_n(x_0)\to f(x_0)$, you might conclude from this that $f_n(x_0+h)\to f(x_0+h)$ uniformly in $h$, which is the same thing as to say that $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ uniformly in $x$.

Comment: Thank You. This was one I was looking for. The integration one is good too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick approach is via integration. Fix $x_0\in [a, b]$ such that $f_n(x_0)$ converges. Then write 
$$f_n(x)=f_n(x_0)+\int_{x_0}^x f'_n(y)\, dy.$$
The right hand side converges uniformly to $f(x_0)+\int_{x_0}^x f'(y)\, dy$, because 
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\left\lvert f_n(x_0)-f(x_0)+\int_{x_0}^x f'_n(y)-f'(y)\, dy\right\rvert &\le \lvert f_n(x_0)-f(x_0)\rvert +\left\lvert \int_{x_0}^x \lvert f'_n(y)-f'(y)\rvert\, dy\right\rvert \\ 
&\le  \lvert f_n(x_0)-f(x_0)\rvert+(b-a)\lVert f'_n-f'\rVert_\infty, 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
and the right hand side is now a numerical sequence which tends to 0 by assumption. Since 
$$f(x_0)+\int_{x_0}^x f'(y)\, dy=f(x), $$
we have thus proven that $f_n \to f$ uniformly.

The only small disadvantage of this proof is that it requires the fundamental theorem of calculus and so it requires integrability of $f'_n$. This is certainly the case if $f_n\in C^1([a,b])$, but the theorem still holds for more pathological functions which are not the integral of their derivative. For this (small) generalization you can consult Rudin, *Principles of mathematical analysis*, chapter 7.